# Karma + jasmine + moment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Have a question:
moved karma tests to linux server with another timezone and some tests failing where moment is used.

Has anyone ideas how to solve this? Because changed timezone on my local machine and they failling also.

Example test:

```
//dayrange is timestamp
expect(dayRange.end).toBe(moment('2015-10-07 08:00').toDate().getTime());
```

Comment: Could you please share more of the test? I have a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve.